# Argument validation in F# struct constructor

Tags: c#, f#, struct, c#-to-f#

Here is a trivial C# struct that does some validation on the ctor argument:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Foo(string name)
        : this()
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(name.StartsWith("A"));
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I've managed to translate this into an F# class:

```ml
type Foo(name : string) = 
    do 
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException> (name.StartsWith "A")
    member x.Name = name
```

However, I can't translate this to a structure in F#:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Foo = 
    val Name : string
    new(name : string) = { do Contract.Requires<ArgumentException> (name.StartsWith "A"); Name = name }
```

This gives compile errors:

> Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of 
>   the form 'seq { ... }'
>
> This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must
>   either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify 
>   a call to a super class constructor.

I've had a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx) but they do not cover argument validation.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `then` block after initializing structs. It is described for classes in your first [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx) in section *Executing Side Effects in Constructors*, but it works for structs as well.

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Foo = 
    val Name : string
    new(name : string) = { Name = name } 
                         then if name.StartsWith("A") then failwith "Haiz"
```

**UPDATE:**

Another way closer to your example is to use `;` (sequential composition) and parentheses to combine expressions:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Foo = 
    val Name : string
    new(name : string) = 
        { Name = ((if name.StartsWith("A") then failwith "Haiz"); name) }
```

Comment: Ah, I'd tried using then within the { }. When that didn't work I assumed it was because it could only be used in a class constructor (as suggested in that section the linked article). When you say "not entirely the same", is that because the validation comes after the assignment?

Comment: Yes, the object has been constructed before the exception is thrown.

Comment: I tested your example from C# by calling `foo = new Foo("A")` within a try/catch and then examining the foo instance within the catch block. I expected foo.Name to equal "A", but instead it was null i.e. the object had not been constructed. In which case your solution _is_ equivalent to the C# code.

Comment: Great, thank you for the info. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to avoid explicit fields (`val`) and `then`, two relatively esoteric features, you could use a static `Create` method and stick to the more common type definition syntax:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Foo private (name: string) = 
  member x.Name = name
  static member Create(name: string) =
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException> (name.StartsWith "A")
    Foo(name)
```

Comment: Good to know about that option - I didn't realise that you can define structures using the same syntax as classes (apart from the [<Struct>]). However, I'm not so keen on the Create method - I prefer a simple ctor so will stick with learning val and then.