# Is it possible to enforce that a Record respects some invariants?

Tags: f#, record, refinement-type

Suppose I wanted to create a Record type that represents acceptable min/max bounds:

```
type Bounds = { Min: float; Max: float }
```

Is there a way to enforce that Min < Max? It is easy to write a validateBounds function, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Edit: I realized that for this specific example I could probably get away with exposing two properties and re-order the arguments, so let's say we were trying to do

```
type Person = { Name: string }
```

and Name needs to have at least one character.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Records don't give you an explicit constructor.

Comment: No, you'd need a stronger type system like the refinement types in [F*](http://rise4fun.com/FStar). Code Contracts can enforce this invariant in C#, but AFAIK the Code Contracts contract checker still doesn't work correctly for F# projects.

Comment: You may consider to switch to structs which also give you structural equality. Pattern matching can be facilitated through active patterns. The advantange is that it's easy to enforce variants [using explicit constructors and then construct, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600574/argument-validation-in-f-struct-constructor).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's another solution based on protection levels:

```fsharp
module MyModule =
    type Bounds = private { _min: float; _max: float } with
        // define accessors, a bit overhead
        member public this.Min = this._min
        member public this.Max = this._max
        static member public Make(min, max) =
            if min > max then raise (ArgumentException("bad values"))
            {_min=min; _max=max}

    // The following line compiles fine,
    // e.g. within your module you can do "unsafe" initialization
    let myBadBounds = {_min=10.0; _max=5.0}

open MyModule
let b1 = Bounds.Make(10.0, 20.0) // compiles fine
let b1Min = b1.Min
let b2 = Bounds.Make(10.0, 5.0) // throws an exception
// The following line does not compile: the union cases of the type 'Bounds'
// are not accessible from this code location
let b3 = {_min=10.0; _max=20.0}
// The following line takes the "bad" value from the module
let b4 = MyModule.myBadBounds
```

Comment: That is clever - I didn't know you could make the "Constructor" private.

Comment: It is not written in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx), but if you try `type Bounds = {private min: float}`, the compiler outs: *error FS0575: Accessibility modifiers are not permitted on record fields. Use 'type R = internal ...' or 'type R = private ...' to give an accessibility to the whole representation.*

Comment: @Mathias: Keep in mind you lose most of the benefits of records when the fields are private. Might as well use a class.

Comment: @Daniel: you do get to keep free comparison at least though. Throw in a `Bounds` active pattern like I showed for my class solution and this might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 7):

I think your best bet is a static member:

```
type Bounds = { Min: float; Max: float }
    with
        static member Create(min: float, max:float) =
            if min >= max then
                invalidArg "min" "min must be less than max"

            {Min=min; Max=max}
```

and use it like

```
> Bounds.Create(3.1, 2.1);;
System.ArgumentException: min must be less than max
Parameter name: min
   at FSI_0003.Bounds.Create(Double min, Double max) in C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FsOverflow\FsOverflow\Script2.fsx:line 5
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005.main@()
Stopped due to error
> Bounds.Create(1.1, 2.1);;
val it : Bounds = {Min = 1.1;
                   Max = 2.1;}
```

However, as you point out, the big down-side of this approach is that there is nothing preventing the construction of an "invalid" record directly. If this is a major concern, consider using a class type for guaranteeing your invariants:

```
type Bounds(min:float, max:float) = 
    do
        if min >= max then
            invalidArg "min" "min must be less than max"

    with
        member __.Min = min
        member __.Max = max
```

together with an active pattern for convenience similar to what you get with records (specifically with regard to pattern matching):

```
let (|Bounds|) (x:Bounds) =
    (x.Min, x.Max)
```

all together:

```
> let bounds = Bounds(2.3, 1.3);;
System.ArgumentException: min must be less than max
Parameter name: min
   at FSI_0002.Bounds..ctor(Double min, Double max) in C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FsOverflow\FsOverflow\Script2.fsx:line 4
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@()
Stopped due to error
> let bounds = Bounds(1.3, 2.3);;

val bounds : Bounds

> let isMatch = match bounds with Bounds(1.3, 2.3) -> "yes!" | _ -> "no";;

val isMatch : string = "yes!"

> let isMatch = match bounds with Bounds(0.3, 2.3) -> "yes!" | _ -> "no";;

val isMatch : string = "no"
```

Comment: I was considering this - it looks to me like a factory method. The one issue, though, is that nothing prevents a caller to bypass the Create method and instantiate an "invalid" record. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are absolutely correct, the Create method could always be bypassed. It's certainly a big issue, enough that you may consider making the record private, or otherwise opting for more complex class type.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's funny, because I had similar gripes in the past with the C# struct and its always-present empty constructor, which also causes validation headaches.

Comment: And yes, it looks like a Class is a way to address the issue - at the cost of some of the Record benefits, like out-of-the-box value-wise equality, etc...

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, the active pattern gets us part way there, but not all the way.

Answer (score 0):

A dodgy solution for the string example - use a DU

```
type cleverstring = |S of char * string
```

This will force the string to have at least one charcter.  Then you can just use `cleverstring` instead of `string` in your record, although you probably want to write some wrapper functions to make it look like a string.

Comment: Oh - that is deliciously ugly :)

Comment: It actually makes slightly more sense when you use it in a parser