# F# - Restricting Discriminated Union case in function input

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Let's say I'm trying to build a simple Stack in F# as follows:

```
type Stack =
| Empty
| Stack of String list
```

(I know I can define it recursively but for this example, let's assume I'd like to have a list in there)

Then I define a push operation like this:

```
let push item deck =
    match deck with
    | Empty -> Stack [item]
    | Stack d -> Stack (item::d)
```

But when I reach the pop operation... I'm not having success. I wanted to do something like this:

```
let pop (Stack d) =
    match d with
    | h::[] -> h,Empty
    | h::t -> h,(Stack t)
```

For now, let's also try to ignore the fact that I might want a peek/pop pair of operations instead of returning a tuple. What I wanted to try was to write a pop operation which would only accept a Stack which is not empty in the first place.

In other words, I only wanted this function to accept one of the cases of the Discriminated Union. However, I immediately get the warning: "Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'Empty' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)'.

As expected (after the warning), the following code:

```
let empty = Empty
let s,st = pop empty
```

... compiles and fails at run time. I wanted it to fail at compile time.

I'm aware I could use other options for this, such as:

```
let pop stack =
    match stack with
    | Empty -> None, Empty
    | Stack (h::[]) -> Some h,Empty
    | Stack (h::t) -> Some h,(Stack t)
```

or:

```
let pop stack =
    match stack with
    | Empty -> Error "Empty Stack"
    | Stack (h::[]) -> Ok (h,Empty)
    | Stack (h::t) -> Ok (h,(Stack t))
```

(and on both of these cases I might not even need the Empty case at all...)

But I was trying to make something more restrictive. So... what am I missing here? Is there a way to achieve what I was attempting? Does it even make any sense to want that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what you're trying to achieve carefully. Consider the following function:

```
let foo (s: Stack) = pop s
```

Should `foo` compile or should it be rejected? Think about it.

I will assume here that you have already thought about it, and offered the only reasonable answer: the "restriction" that you seek should now apply to `foo` as well. That is, whoever calls `foo` must *also* supply only non-empty stack.

Ok, fair enough. But let's go all the way to the turtles:

```
let main argv = 
    printf "Provide directive: "

    let s = 
        match Console.ReadLine() with
        | "empty" -> Empty
        | _ -> Stack [1; 2; 3]

    let p = pop s

    0
```

Now should this program compile or be rejected? Obviously, it depends on the user input. *The type of the program depends on runtime values*. This is actually an active area of research, and there is a name for it: such program is called *[Dependently Typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)*. In plain terms it's when values (may) carry types with them, but unlike .NET RTTI, the compiler has visibility into those types and can prove things about their relationships. Fascinating stuff.

F#, for better or worse, doesn't support dependent types, and probably never will.

---

Now, I will assume that you're ok with not having dependent types, and would like instead to have your "restriction" only for cases when it is definitely *known* (at compile time) that the stack is not empty.

If this is the case, then your problem is easily solvable by splitting your DU in two:

```
type NonEmptyStack<'a> = NonEmptyStack of top: 'a * rest: 'a list
type Stack<'a> = Empty | NonEmpty of NonEmptyStack<'a>

let push item stack =
    match stack with
    | Empty -> NonEmptyStack (item, [])
    | NonEmpty (NonEmptyStack (top, rest)) -> NonEmptyStack (item, top::rest)

let pop (NonEmptyStack (top,rest)) = 
    match rest with
    | i::tail -> (top, Stack (NonEmptyStack (i, tail)))
    | _ -> (top, Empty)
```

Notice how `push` always returns a non-empty stack, and `pop` accepts only non-empty stack. The types encode the meaning. This is what they're supposed to do.

Comment: Great answer. I had already thought about the points you've raised, and yes, I would want both your examples to fail during compilation, exactly because I'd want the option to transfer the burden of writing safe code to the caller. So, if the caller generates a potentially unsafe (empty) stack, he'd have the responsibility to check it first. The other solution you've mentioned is the one I was going to provide as my own answer but since you've already provided such a well-written one, I'll accept yours. Thanks a lot for all the input.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your model -- there are two ways to represent an empty stack:

```
let empty1 = Empty
let empty2 = Stack []
```

Given this, it's not clear how you want it to behave. This is why I would suggest either going with a recursively defined stack, or or just using a list. Here's your options:

```
// type alias
type Stack<'a> = 'a list
// single-case DU
type Stack<'a> = Stack of 'a list
// traditional recursive type (which happens to be exactly equivalent to list<'a>)
type Stack<'a> = Empty | Stack of 'a * Stack<'a>
```

That said, if you *really* just want to keep it the way you have it right now, and get it to compile, you just need to match the extra "empty" representation:

```
let pop stack =
    match stack with
    | Empty | Stack [] -> None, Empty
    | Stack (h::[]) -> Some h,Empty
    | Stack (h::t) -> Some h,(Stack t)
```

Comment: It compiles just fine. I wanted it to fail compilation when you try to feed an empty stack to the function. But agreed there are two ways to represent an empty stack, still, I don't really believe this changes the question, does it?

Comment: @PedroGoes oh I see. This isn't possible to do with the types as you have them defined, since the compiler can't know whether or not you passed in an empty stack. I would suggest using a non-empty-list type for these kinds of operations: `type NonEmptyList<'a> = Singleton of 'a | NonEmptyList of 'a * NonEmptyList<'a>`

Comment: thanks for the inputs... that's the whole point of the question... there's no way to restrict the input of a function to only accept a single case of a discriminated union?

Comment: Right. Take a look at languages with Dependent types.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930135/f-limitations-of-discriminated-unions?rq=1

Comment: You actually can restrict the input to a case, but it's not enforced at compile time, and has nothing specifically to do with DUs. Instead you get an exception at runtime if you don't call it with the same value. I don't see any sensible use for it. Example: `let f (Empty: Stack) = ...` Another example: `let f 7 = "You can only call me with 7 as argument."` and one example you already know of is `let f () = "You can only call me with () as argument."`

Comment: @BentTranberg thanks! I agree there does not seem to exist a sensible use for it that way. What I was wondering is if there was a way to achieve it at compile time. Could have been useful in my opinion if you were simply unable to call pop with an empty stack. The only way I found that MAYBE could achieve what I was trying to do proved itself to be too cumbersome to seem useful. Still, I'll post it later here to add to the discussion.