# FSharp define type in terms of predicate

Tags: types, f#

I have code that looks something like

```
type U0 = E1|E2|E3...
type T2 = {field1: string; field2: string; field3: string}
type T1 = T2*T2*T2
type T0 = T1*T1*T1
```

And I want to enforce some predicate `P1` on the type of `field1` that `field1` such that `(GetUnionCases typeof<U0>).contains(field1)`. I hope that isn't too abstract.

So to do this, I'd like to introduce the type P1, with a definition something like

```
type P1(x) = (GetUnionCases typeof<U0>).map(fun x -> x.Name).contains(x)
```

Comment: You may consider playing with protection levels combined with a named constructor, just like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13925632/974789).

Answer (score 2):

In general, F# does not have any form of [refinement types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_%28computing%29) that would let you attach arbitrary predicates as constraints to type declarations.

It is difficult to give a more specific answer based on your somewhat abstract example, but very often, it is possible to design the domain (your types) differently, so that the predicate is enforced by construction - in other words, design your types so that any value of the type automatically satisfies the predicate. The [designing with types article series](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html) has some practical examples showing that.

I do not fully follow your example, but say you want to make sure that the string of `field1` contains the value `E1`, the string `field2` contains the value `E2` (as a sub-string) and so on. So:

```
{  field1 = "hi E1 there" } // valid
{  field1 = "hi there" } // invalid
```

You could change the type of `field1` from `string` to `string * string` representing the prefix and the suffix of the string "E1" and so you would be only able to construct:

```
{ field1 = "hi", "there" } // valid
```

There is now no way to create a value that does not implicitly have "E1" as a sub-string!
I'm pretty sure I misunderstood your example, but I hope this demonstrates the idea...