# Creating an F# record type with a constant value

Tags: inheritance, f#, recordtype

Let's say I have a record defined thusly...

```
type Employee = {Name : string; Salary : int}
```

and I want another type where `Salary` is fixed. I'd like to be able to say...

```
type Manager = {Name: string; Salary : int = 250000}
```

...but it seems I can't.

What options do I have to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give your record a **read-only property**:

```
type Manager = 
    {
        Name: string
    }
     member this.Salary = 250000
```

FSI example:

```
> let m = { Name = "Foo" };;

val m : Manager = {Name = "Foo";}

> m.Name;;
val it : string = "Foo"
> m.Salary;;
val it : int = 250000
```

Comment: Bingo. I'll take that, Mr. Seemann. Awesome work on your TDD F# course on Pluralsight BTW.  Just finished watching it.

Comment: Is that first code sample missing a `with`?  Or maybe the `with` wasn't required back when this was written?  When I tried it today, it wouldn't take it without `with`.

Comment: @RyanLundy I just tried from an F# script file, as well as from *F# Interactive*, and the above syntax worked for me in both cases...

Comment: @MarkSeemann OK, I see what happened...and how peculiar.  I had the opening brace after the `=`.  Doing it that way, the `with` is required, but doing it with the braces exactly as you have them above, it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

F# records are immutable, so all field values are "fixed", in your terms.

If your goal is to avoid specifying `Salary` upon construction, the simplest way is to make a "constructor":

```
type Manager = {Name : string; Salary : int} with
    static member Make name =
        {Manager.Name=name; Salary=250000}
```

Note 1. I used `Manager.Name` so that it did not interfere with `Employee` construction;
Note 2. Also, this approach does not even prevent from keeping a single type `Employee` that will also gracefully handle Manager's creation; just call the method e.g. `MakeManager` for clarity.

A `static` method does not prohibit someone (a developer who uses your library) from manually creating a `Manager` with wrong salary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925632/974789) for how to prevent such creation.

Answer (score 2):

Record type could have members, e.g.

```
  type Employee = {Name : string; Salary : int}
  type Manager =
    {Name: string; }
    member x.Salary with get() = 250000
  let manager1 = {Manager.Name = "manager1"}
  let manager2 = { manager1 with Manager.Name = "manager2"}
  let salary = manager1.Salary // fsi: val salary : int = 250000
```

But here if a manager is an employee, I would use normal classes and inheritance instead of records. It is perfectly fine to use normal classes from F# and immutability could be achieved by avoiding public setters.